# BIRT report error when connecting to MySql database

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, reporting-services, birt

This is something with BIRT reporting tool.

I have configured BIRT Report server and everything seems ok. I can run BIRT default report as well. But when I run a custom report which connecting to MySql im getting this error. I have pasted the stack trace

```
    org.eclipse.birt.report.service.api.ReportServiceException: Error happened while running the report.
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.throwDummyException(ReportEngineService.java:1114)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runAndRenderReport(ReportEngineService.java:943)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.runAndRenderReport(BirtViewerReportService.java:973)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtGetPageAllActionHandler.__execute(BirtGetPageAllActionHandler.java:131)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractBaseActionHandler.execute(AbstractBaseActionHandler.java:90)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.__executeAction(AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.java:47)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.executeAction(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:143)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.BirtDocumentProcessor.handleGetPageAll(BirtDocumentProcessor.java:183)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.process(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:112)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.endpoint.BirtSoapBindingImpl.getUpdatedObjects(BirtSoapBindingImpl.java:66)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
   at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
   at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
   at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
   at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
   at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
   at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doPost(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:265)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
   at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:122)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter.doFilter(ViewerFilter.java:68)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Error happened while running the report.
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask.handleFatalExceptions(EngineTask.java:2380)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:191)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:77)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runAndRenderReport(ReportEngineService.java:937)
... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/Signature
   at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
   at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.findDriver(JDBCDriverManager.java:843)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.loadAndRegisterDriver(JDBCDriverManager.java:984)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.loadAndRegisterDriver(JDBCDriverManager.java:956)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.doConnect(JDBCDriverManager.java:285)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.getConnection(JDBCDriverManager.java:236)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Connection.connectByUrl(Connection.java:252)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Connection.open(Connection.java:162)
   at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaConnection.open(OdaConnection.java:250)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:165)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSource.newConnection(DataSource.java:224)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSource.open(DataSource.java:212)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.DataSourceRuntime.openOdiDataSource(DataSourceRuntime.java:217)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.openDataSource(QueryExecutor.java:434)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.prepareExecution(QueryExecutor.java:322)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedQuery.doPrepare(PreparedQuery.java:463)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.produceQueryResults(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:190)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.execute(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:178)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedOdaDSQuery.execute(PreparedOdaDSQuery.java:178)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.execute(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:637)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DteDataEngine.doExecuteQuery(DteDataEngine.java:152)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.AbstractDataEngine.execute(AbstractDataEngine.java:275)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.executeQuery(ExecutionContext.java:1947)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.QueryItemExecutor.executeQuery(QueryItemExecutor.java:80)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.TableItemExecutor.execute(TableItemExecutor.java:62)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.dup.SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.execute(SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.java:43)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.execute(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:46)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.l18n.LocalizedReportItemExecutor.execute(LocalizedReportItemExecutor.java:34)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:65)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:92)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:100)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:181)
... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.lang.Signature
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 90 more
```

Below I have mentioned the procedures that I have followed to deploy the report.
(Followed this documentation http://www.eclipse.org/birt/documentation/integrating/viewer-setup.php
)

1. Created a report using eclipse and when I run this report I can see the output.
2. I copied .rptdesign file to "Report" folder in birt-viewer
3. Copied "mysql-connector-java-5.1.33-bin.jar" and "aspectj-1.8.2.jar" to WEB-INF/lib folder in birt-viewer
4. Then used the following url to run the report `http://localhost:8080/birt-viewer/run?__report=Report\new_report.rptdesign`

When I run this url im getting the above error. Please help with this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you make use of Java 8, i am not sure if this is officially supported by BIRT yet. You should try the same with Java 7. Otherwise put aspect*.jar file in the lib folder of your JRE install.

By the way, with an application server such Tomcat the recommended approach to connect reports to databases is connection pooling rather than a direct JDBC access. Defining a connection pool in birt reports and in Tomcat is straight and easy, see an article [here](http://www.visioneo.org/knowledge-base/-/knowledge_base/article/122720).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My Java version is 7 and update 47. Anyway I have removed BIRT version 4.4.2 and installed 2.2.6. Everything seems ok now.